# My onPostExecute Method doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

For some reason my doinbackground method executes but the onPost execute doesn't I put the override annotations and matched the parameters and i'm also doing task.execute instead of just calling the doinbackground but it still doesnt execute.
this is what my code looks like:

Android activity:

```
package com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;

import com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler.MyApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements HttpCallback, OnClickListener{

    private EditText user_;
    private EditText pass_;
    private Button login_;
    private Button signUp_;
    private MyApp appState_;
    private String url_ = "http://192.168.1.110:8888/vshare/account/create";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Workout Scheduler");
        MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
        appState_ = appState;
        user_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
        pass_ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        login_ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        signUp_ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        appState_.setUser("default");
        appState_.setPass("default");
        login_.setOnClickListener(this);
        signUp_.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.loginButton){
            Log.i("amre", "button pushed");
            appState_.setUser(user_.getText().toString());
            appState_.setPass(pass_.getText().toString());
            try {
                login(url_);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewCreate.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.signupButton){
            appState_.setUser(user_.getText().toString());
            appState_.setPass(pass_.getText().toString());
        }

    }

    public void login(String server) throws Exception{
        Log.i("button", "login");
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("user", new StringBody(appState_.getUser()));
        entity.addPart("pass", new StringBody(appState_.getPass()));
        LoginTask t = new LoginTask(entity, url_, this);
        t.execute();
        Log.i("Task", "Executed");
    }

    public void onResponse(HttpResponse resp) {

        String line = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        Log.i("reuslt:", result);
    }

    public void onError(Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I call login in the onclick method which calls t.execute.
This is what my async task looks like:

```
package com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse> {

    private HttpEntity entity_;

    private String url_;

    private HttpCallback callback_;

    public LoginTask(HttpEntity entity, String url, HttpCallback callback){
        super();
        entity_ = entity;
        url_ = url;
        callback_ = callback;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("onPost", "executing");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback_.onResponse(result);


    }



    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("doinbackground", "executing");
        HttpResponse resp = null;
        try{
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_);
            Log.i("doinbackground", "httppst");
            post.setEntity(entity_);
            Log.i("doinbackground", "setentity");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.i("doinbackground", "client");
            resp = client.execute(post);
            Log.i("doinbackground", "resp");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("doinbackground", "error");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return resp;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your output? Is `"resp"` ever shown?

Comment: I just took another look at the log cat and it looks like it's not getting a response because the right after it isnt being printed. I guess theres something wrong with the serverside

Comment: Post execute method wont call if you get exceptions in doInBackground method

Answer (score 0):

Please check had you given internet permission in manifest or not .. if internet is working fine, check that your downloading Url is valid or not.. if your  downloading url is not valid it raises the exception in  doInBackground method , so onPostExecute method wont call